# Why should both use joint_states and transform

Tags: urdf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder now that  both robot_state_publisher and transform_broadcaster send kinematics information to /tf topic, why should we use both? I think I must misunderstand sth, though I have gone through tf and urdf tutorial.

Here is the link where it makes r2d2 robot move with using robot_state_publisher and sendTransform
[Tutorial: using urdf with robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251362/why-should-both-use-joint_states-and-transform/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2017-01-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Shawnysh,

As I think you are aware, the `robot_state_publisher` is used to publish the state of the robot to tf. It publishes the transforms between the links as a function of the joint states.

The sendTransform is used to publish a transform from `odom` to `axis`, which happens to be the root frame of the robot. As you can see in the code, this is done such that `axis` performs a circular motion around `odom`. If you then choose `odom` as your fixed frame (as noted in the last step for the linked tutorial) you will see the robot move around the origin. As `robot_state_publisher` only publishes the transforms *between* the links, they are also updated for a moving 'base' frame (in this case: `axis`).

Alternatively, if you would select `axis` as your fixed frame, the robot will make the same motions, but not move in a circular pattern.

I hope that clears things up.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-01-06**:
Thanks a lot.
It helps!